# How can I write a query with 2 states?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have table **Customer**:

```
Id  Code    Name
1   100     John
2   200     Jack
3   300     Mike
4   400     Betty
```

And table **SaleType**:

```
Id  Code    Name
1   1000    cash
2   2000    cheque
3   3000    free
```

And a table that describe which customer has which sale type named **SaleType_Customer**

```
Id  SaleTypeID  CustomerID
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   2           1
4   2           3
```

I want to write a query that takes the **SaleTypes** of a customer. But if the customer is not in table **SaleType_Customer** the query returns all of **SaleTypes**. How can I write this query?

My query:

```
SELECT  SaleType.ID, SaleType.Code, SaleType.Name
 FROM SaleType left outer join SaleType_Customer on SaleType.Id = SaleType_Customer.SaleTypeID 

Where SaleType_Customer.CustomerID= 1
```

I want the result for John (id=1):

```
Id  Code    Name
1   1000    cash
2   2000    cheque
```

And for Betty (id=4) is complete because she is not in **SaleType_Customer**:

```
Id  Code    Name
1   1000    cash
2   2000    cheque
3   3000    free
```

How should I  write my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct SaleType.ID, SaleType.Code, SaleType.Name
 FROM Customer left join SaleType_Customer  
on CustomerID = Customer.Id 
,SaleType
where (SaleTypeID = SaleType.Id or SaleTypeID is NULL)
and Customer.ID= 4;
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bf5e3/33)

Comment: Both are true. Which one is faster?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SaleType.ID, SaleType.Code, SaleType.Name
  FROM SaleType
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM SaleType_Customer
         WHERE SaleType_Customer.Customerid = 4)
UNION

SELECT SaleType.ID, SaleType.Code, SaleType.Name
  FROM SaleType
 INNER JOIN SaleType_Customer
    ON SaleType_Customer.Saletypeid = SaleType.Id
 WHERE SaleType_Customer.Customerid = 4
```

[Sqlfiddle sample (oracle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07e00/1)

Comment: Both are true. Which one is faster?

Comment: It seems @snyder answer is faster, due to execution plan. I must admit that is more innovative also.